# Using FFMpeg to match images with videos

Tags: ffmpeg, video, images, dvd, naming

I've recently been ripping some of my DVDs, however the output isn't in order or labelled in a helpful way. I want to use FFMPEG to find still frames in these episodes in order to name them.

I can search for a single image in a video like so:

```bash
ffmpeg  -i video.mkv -r 1 -loop 1 -i frame.jpg -an -filter_complex "blend=difference:shortest=1,blackframe=90:32" -f null -
```

However, I'd like to search a video with multiple images and identify which images were found.

The idea here is I can use images from TMDB for each episode, and based on which image is found in the video, I can use it to name the file. I'm not sure if this is possible, or if I have to go the slower route of searching one image at a time, per video.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you better use Python script (probably with OpenCV). Even if it's possible to use FFmpeg for identifying if an image exists in a video file, you still need some programming for matching the names. Using programming we can think of efficient solutions like iterating multiple images for each video frame...